# Fan of my MacBook Air is Running at High Speed and Making Noise

Tags: macbook-pro

I have this noise problem recently. Everything was good a few weeks ago.

[image]

Comment: When was the last time it was stripped & cleaned? Dust is always the first suspect.

Answer (score 1):

[Reset NVRAM](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063) & [Reset SMC](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201295)

If that doesn't help you might want to open up your MacBook (or get it opened up by a technician) to check for dust or other clogging. An Apple Certified Service Provider will also have the ability to do a hardware test, the fan itself could be the problem as well.